# How do I turn off a specific Audio when my player dies?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

So I'm making a Ball game where the goal is to dodge obstacles and reach the end of the level.

I've made a wind effect sound for when the player reaches a certain amount of speed.. however, when the player hits an obstacle and dies, the sound of the wind continues.

My question is: How do I turn off a specific Audio when my player dies? I'm not quite sure what functions & stuff I should put in my code.

Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObstacleCollisionBig : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject destroyedObstacle;

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo)
    {
        if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Player")
        {
            Instantiate(destroyedObstacle, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>().Play("ShatterBig");   
            Destroy(gameObject);    
        }  
    }
}
```

If I wasn't clear enough, feel free to ask about more information.

Thanks in advance,
E.W

Comment: Hi E.W. Do you have any relevant code you can show us? I'm not very familiar with Unity, so apologises if code isn't relevant here :-) P.S. I've removed your Visual Studio tag since that should only be used for questions about the Visual Studio application.

Comment: Hey! I added a link for my 'ObstacleCollision' script. The script enables when the player hits an obstacle. That is also where I want to add some sort of code to disable my 'Wind' audio. Thanks!

Comment: What plays the wind? is it a specific wind gameobject on the scene which has 1 audioSource ?

Comment: Can you show us the Play() function in AudioManager class? Assuming that's how you play the wind

Comment: Hey, I have an audiomanager that runs all of the sound files. I've setup a way to adjust the pitch and the volume of the sounds.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day, you would need to grab a reference to your `AudioSource` object and call [.Stop()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.Stop.html) on it.

As @SHAI might be suggesting, perhaps your `AudioManager` already has this functionality wrapped away in it (or if not, can be added to it).